# Python crashes when I import tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I try to import tensorflow my python crashes. I tried uninstalling it and installing it again, but It isn't still working. Here is a picture of the command prompt when I try to import it.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, but instead copy-and-paste the error message. While this is a bit cumbersome in the windows terminal, it's still very inconvenient for users here to follow a link and potentially not be able to copy and paste error messages. Regarding your problem: this looks really bad. If it was me, I would use a C-debugger like windbg to see if I can get a stacktrace. But this is quite advanced. My suggestion would be to remove the install, and try and install new, possibly following a different tutorial.

Comment: Sorry for posting the screenshot but there is no error message. Python just closes after trying to import it. I tried to install it again but it didn’t do it

Comment: Then I would suggest installing windbg and try running through it. Because unless we learn where the crash actually happens, there is nothing left to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what the error is here.

1. try to `pip list` to see all packages

if no tensorflow seen then just `pip install tensorflow`

2. or `print dir(tensorflow)` to see functions

It seems you aren't executing anything but just importing the module.

Comment: Just trying to import the library closes python. That's why im in directory again

Comment: If it was just an import, the python prompt would reappear. However the OP is thrown back to the CMD.EXE prompt, meaning python has crashed hard.

Comment: Yeah, true. Check this out - seems to be a similar issue. [tensorflow causes whole python to crash](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8676)