# tensorflow can be imported but it shows undefined when use it

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed tensorflow (GPU version) several days ago and it worked well. However, today I imported tensorflow as `import tensorflow as tf` and when I try to use it such as `tf.constant()`, it shows `NameError: name 'tf' is not defined`. I'm new to tensorflow. Anyone knows the reason?

I found I have the same issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8676
I can run my script without any error message but there is no result.

Comment: There is no error message when I imported tensorflow

Comment: Have you used virtual environment at the time when you've tested it first time? If so, you need to activate virtual environment first, and then run the script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to run import tensorflow as tf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365418/unable-to-run-import-tensorflow-as-tf)

Comment: I indeed activated the virtual environment where tensorflow is installed

Comment: Nope. I only have a NameError

Comment: which IDE you are using currently?

Comment: Syder in Anaconda. Also, I have the same issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54172772/python-crashes-when-i-import-tensorflow

Comment: @Yiming Che, Is your issue resolved now ? Else, please try new virtual environment with a fresh TF installation might fix the issue.

Comment: @YimingChe, From the comment, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8676#issuecomment-292590343, can you please confirm if switching to Anaconda has resolved your issue? Thanks!

Comment: @TensorflowWarriors, I have already solved it by reinstall everything. Thanks for the suggestion.